# Find a value in a list given the a value contained in the first position of the list

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have a list such as:

`list={{90.,1.41813*10^-7},{90.,3.64722*10^-7},{89.9999,6.92632*10^-7},{89.9999,1.1241*10^-6},{89.9999,1.65807*10^-6},{89.9998,2.29371*10^-6},{89.9997,3.03034*10^-6},{89.9996,3.86738*10^-6},{89.9996,4.80431*10^-6},{89.9995,5.84068*10^-6},{89.9993,6.97609*10^-6},{89.9992,8.21018*10^-6},{89.9991,9.5426*10^-6},{89.999,0.000010973},{89.9988,0.0000125012},{89.9986,0.0000141269},{89.9985,0.0000158498},{89.9983,0.0000176696},{89.9981,0.0000195862},{89.9979,0.0000215994},{89.9977,0.0000237089},{89.9975,0.0000259145},{89.9972,0.0000282162},{89.997,0.0000306136},{89.9968,0.0000331066},{89.9965,0.0000356951},{89.9962,0.0000383789},{89.9959,0.0000411578},{89.9957,0.0000440317},{89.9954,0.0000470005},{89.995,0.0000500641},{89.9947,0.0000532222},{89.9944,0.0000564747},{89.9941,0.0000598216},{89.9937,0.0000632627}}`

How can I find the value that corresponds to the the second position of one of the sublist given the value of the first position?. For example, inside the list I have `{89.9983,0.0000176696}` how can I find the number `0.0000176696` given the value of `89.9983` which is contained in the list.

EDIT: I tried using something like `Select[list, MemberQ[89.9983,#] &][[2]]` but it does not work

Thank you.

Comment: Try Select[list, SameQ[#[[1]], 89.9983] &]

Comment: If you are sure that the value is there, you could use `89.9983 /. Rule @@@ list`.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you! This works great!. You should put it as an answer too. I appreciate it.

Comment: You can use `Position`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way could be

```
num = 89.9983 ;
Cases[list,{ num , x_} :> x]

(* {0.0000176696} *)
```

Comment: Thank you Nasser!. This work great. However, is it possible to obtain the value without `{}`?. I tried `Flatten[Cases[lista, { 89.9983, x_} :> x]]` but it is still with the `{}`. Thanks

Comment: @John Use `FirstCase` instead of `Cases` or `First@Cases[...]`.

Comment: Slightly modifying this with `OrderlessPatternSequence` makes this really powerful, Nasser. Check out my answer, it leads me to believe there is an ideal arrangement for a method like this!!

Answer (score 3):

```
data//Pick[#[[All,2]], #[[All,1]], 89.9983]&
```

> {0.0000176696}

```
%[[1]]
```

> 0.0000176696

If the use of `Select` is required, maybe:

```
Select[list, #[[1]]==89.9983 &][[1,2]]
```

> 0.0000176696

(But IMO `Pick` is a very powerful command in situations like this)

Comment: A 'just for fun' `Reap/Sow` solution: `Reap[Sow[#2, #===89.9983]&@@@list,True][[2,1,1]]`

Answer (score 2):

I’ve been really into using `Extract` lately. So, here’s what I would do:

```
Extract[Position[list,{OrderlessPatternSequence[89.9983,___]}]][list][[-1,-1]]

(* 0.0000176696 *)
```

If you know the underlying list structure, that is why we use `[[-1,-1]]`. If we don’t know the value, or, perhaps we only want to write one finder function, we can do the following:

```
FirstCase[list,{OrderlessPatternSequence[89.9983,v___]}:>v]

(* 0.0000176696 *)
```

Further generalization gives us:

```
valueCorrepondingTo[list_,num_]:=FirstCase[list,{OrderlessPatternSequence[num,v___]}:>v];

valueCorrepondingTo[list, 0.0000176696]

(* 89.9983 *)
```

I think this is really cool, this type of functionality and it is completely thanks to `OrderlessPatternSequence`.